# Using decimal.js with Typescript

Tags: typescript, webpack, decimal.js

I am trying to use decimal.js with Typescript on the client side of a simple app that was booted with create-react-app - Typescript 2.8.1.

But even for a simple declaration of `a = new Decimal(1)` I'm just getting an error:

> TypeError: __WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0 default.a is not a constructor

I can't figure out what's exactly the problem. Nothing useful on Google.

Comment: You need to show how you import `Decimal`.

Comment: I tried - 
import { Decimal } from 'decimal.js'; import Decimal from 'decimal.js';
 const decimal = require('decimal.js').

Comment: Please show us the complete file.

Comment: The code works without the the decimal. It's a simple react app that was created using create-react-app script. The app just contains
render() { const a = new Decimal(1); return (<div>a</div>) }.

Answer (score 1):

You have to import as `decimal.js/decimal`.